# Bootstrap Checkbox is not working properly

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using the following mark up and styles (Bootstrap). It shows my checkbox but it is paralysed, that is, it cannot be checked. here is my mark up:
I want something more Bootstrap-ish. I know there are other options to make the checkbox look fancy but that do not solve the problem.

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="checkbox">
    1.
    <input type="checkbox" name="options" id="chk2" />
    <label class="checkbox-label">Option 2</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is how it looks.

[image: checkbox not working]

What exactly is the issue?
If I put the input element inside label I get this ugly thing:

[image]

Comment: Not sure but its look like an outline, it's not recommend to remove him cause of accessibility property but you can try on css : outline: 0;

Comment: If that is only an outline, I want to have that working as check box. the working check box in 2nd example looks so ugly. (http://www.dfc-e.com/metiers/multimedia/opensource/jqtransform/)

Comment: Can you add CSS styles you are using?

Comment: they are standard bootstrap styles, aren't they?

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/nhbdZzvX6eZffDXoIAB5?p=preview doesn't look like your example.

Comment: this is all i could find for you after digging in the source: https://github.com/TalksLab/metro-bootstrap

Comment: Here's some nice styles if they help: http://cssdeck.com/labs/css-checkbox-styles

Comment: I want something bootstrap-ish

Answer (score 8):

```
<input type="checkbox" name="options" id="chk2" />
<label class="checkbox-label">Option 2</label>
```

The problem is with your label. The for attribute must match with the name attribute of your label

Answer (score 5):

Looks need to tweak bootstrap styling for custom checkbox.

Check this

HTML

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="checkbox">
        <label for="check">
            <input type="checkbox" id="check"/>
            <span class="fake-input"></span>
            <span class="fake-label">Option 2</span>
        </label>
    </div>
</div
```

CSS

```
.fake-input {
    float: left;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #9f9f9f;
    background: #fff;
    vertical-align: middle;
    position: relative;
    margin-right: 10px;
    border-radius: 4px;
}
input[type="checkbox"] {
    position: fixed;
    top: -9999px;
    left: -9999px;
}
input[type="checkbox"]:checked + .fake-input:before {
    content:"\2713";
    position: absolute;
    color: #000;
    text-align: center;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Check in [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L7qpgdkk/6/)

Answer (score 4):

Reading around  it looks like you have to style the checked version and the unchecked version.

```
input[type=checkbox]:checked {

}
```

Styling with this tag should solve your problems.

Answer (score 1):

Use "for" attribute to solve this issue.

```
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="checkbox">
    1.
    <input type="checkbox" name="options" id="chk2" />
    <label for="chk2" class="checkbox-label">Option 2</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  <div class="col-md-3">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="" asp-for="">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="" asp-for="">
            </label>
        </div>
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.

Answer (score 0):

It's not due to Bootstrap but to Wordpress.  The checkboxes became visible after I added "display:block;" to the css of the checkbox input tag.

```
<input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="">

input.form-check-input {
display:block;
}
```